# Breeze implementation of 'AND' and 'OR' in the where method

Tags: breeze

Breeze can query for condition1 AND condition2 by using multiple `where` statements. But can it query for condition1 OR condition2?

If not, what is the recommended way of achieving the same effect when using Breeze?

I am currently thinking the only way to do this is to perform the query on the server with a special action method, which creates some problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the problem is the Breeze API and Docs are a little lacking with some typos.

The answer is to use the 'or' method of the Predicate class to create a new Predicate object that is passed to the `where` method.

Given 3 predicates you 'or' them together like so:

```
var newPred = p1.or(p2, p3);
```

or

```
var preds = [p2, p3];
var newPred = p1.or(preds);
```

or fluent method:

```
var p4 = Predicate.create("ShipCity", "startswith", "F")
.or("Size", "gt", 2000);
```

or using the static 'or' method

```
var newPred = Predicate.or(p1, p2, p3);
```

Comment: Hi david004 - Can you point out the typos so we can fix them? It wasn't obvious to me where they are. Thanks!

Comment: Sure Ting. The API for `or(predicates)` method (non-static) has examples that are using the `and` method. And the `or` method is not mentioned at all on the documentation/query-filter page.

Comment: Cool. Thanks! I made a mention of the other operators on the 'Query with a Filter' page and the API docs will be updated in the release following 1.3.5.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Predicate like this sample:

```
var p1 = new breeze.Predicate("IsArchived", "==", false);
var p2 = breeze.Predicate("IsDone", "==", false);
var predicate = p1.and(p2);

var query = new EntityQuery("Todos").where(predicate);
```

Documentation is available here:
http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-filter

Comment: +1 Cause pointed to the methods of the Predicate class. But the wrong method.